# Spring boot security - postman works with REST but curl command fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, curl, spring-security

I'm new to spring boot, especially spring security. I'm carrying out some test on my simple REST service.

There are two of them:
http://localhost:8080/sayhello and http://localhost:8080/api/sayhello

My security config has this:

```
http.httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated();
```

I expect http://localhost:8080/api/sayhello to be authenticated, and not http://localhost:8080/sayhello

When I test http://localhost:8080/sayhello on postman, I see the correct message, which is "Hi!".

But when I run this curl command `curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8080/sayhello/`, I get this:

```
HTTP/1.1 401
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=DDB9A6FF9CBCB9811E141FF17A5D40CB; Path=/; HttpOnly
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 15 Jan 2019 09:11:09 GMT

{"timestamp":"2019-01-15T09:11:09.509+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/sayhello/"}
```

Please, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Everything not under `/api` needs to be at least fully authenticated. That is what you configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default all of your url is authenticated in `Spring-Security`.

line that use used

```
http.httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/**")  // all url with /api/** will be authenticated having role of USER.
                .hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated();
```

Here

```
            .antMatchers("/api/**")
            .hasRole("USER")
```

All url is blocked by Spring-security filter. but api that matches `/api/**` pattern must have role `USER`. except mismatching url must be validated through `Spring-security` Filter.

You should use like this.

```
  .antMatchers("/sayhello/**").permitAll();
```

OR

```
  .anyRequest().permitAll()
```

add this line to your httpAuthentication will allow you to hit api `http://localhost:8080/sayhello` anonymously.

or you may override `configure(WebSecurity web)` like this.. (this will also work).

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/sayhello");
}
```

Thank You..

Answer (score -1):

Spring Security enables URL authentication by default on all of your endpoints. Thus, it is easier to define the permitted URLs instead. Here's a modified code

```
http.httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/sayhello").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .hasRole("USER")
            .fullyAuthenticated();
```